# Is it okay to add a convenience method to the Object class in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Every time you switch between comparing a single value versus comparing multiple values, you have to switch the variable and values around.

```
return if params[:controller] == 'users'
return if ['users', 'sessions', 'admin'].include? params[:controller].
```

The following reverses the syntax of `Array#include`?

```
class Object
  def in?(arr)
    arr.include? self
  end
  def not_in?(arr)
    !(arr.include? self)
  end
end
```

Now you could say:

```
return if params[:controller] == 'users'
return if params[:controller].in? ['users', 'sessions', 'admin']
```

Is there a better/safer way to do this without playing with the Object class?

Comment: There are undoubtedly better and safer ways, but you're using Rails, which is already Monkey Patch Heaven, so why not modify Object? :)

Comment: You could write the first as `return if ['users'].include? params[:controller]`. Only slightly ugly. (I just now noticed that you used `in?` rather than `include?` in your re-write, so I removed the changed-syntax warning..)

Comment: Why do it at all? You already have a fairly short expression to do the same thing. You're also inverting the responsibility in a way that doesn't make sense: you're telling an object to see if it is within some other object, rather than asking an object if it itself contains an object. Generally speaking, if you have to monkey-patch Object, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: Activesupport already defines `in?` in a similar way (this has sometimes been controversial)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just invert the other case to match?

```
return if 'users' == params[:controller]
```

Besides lining up with the multi-value case, it avoids accidental use of the assignment operator `=` instead of the equality operator `==`.

Comment: I was uncomfortable modifying Object, and have decided against it. I chose Mark's answer for the added advantage of avoiding the =/== typo errors, which can create unwelcome 'features'. Thanks to all for your inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Monkey Patch is not always safe, but as you know, it is widely used in Rails.

You can always modify an open class, but make sure all changes have a unique name so it won't cause conflicts.